# Convert String to CLLocationCoordinate2D in swift

Tags: string, swift, converters, cllocation, cllocationcoordinate2d

using Firebase as my backend, I've got a series of strings that are latitude and longitude coordinates, how can I convert them to CLLocationCoordinate2D so that I can use them for annotations? 
Here is the code that gets the info from Firebase every time its updated

```
var UpdateRef = Firebase(url:"https://ici.firebaseio.com/users")

UpdateRef.observeEventType(.ChildChanged, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    let MomentaryLatitude = snapshot.value["latitude"] as? String
    let MomentaryLongitude = snapshot.value["longitude"] as? String
    let ID = snapshot.value["ID"] as? String

    println("\(MomentaryLatitude)")

    var Coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: MomentaryLatitude as
        CLLocationDegrees, longitude: MomentaryLongitude as CLLocationDegrees)

}
```

The last line doesn't work, what should I use instead?

Comment: If, rather than `String`, you used `NSString`, then you can use `doubleValue` to get the numeric value which could then be used as parameters to `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the `doubleValue` property:

```
let MomentaryLatitude = (snapshot.value["latitude"] as NSString).doubleValue
let MomentaryLongitude = (snapshot.value["longitude"] as NSString).doubleValue
```