# How to fix 'When converting from string to CLLocationCoordinate2D."

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm using decoder, And It will show me wrong answer, 1st line is a string, And the second one is I'm converting String to CLLocationCoordinate2D.

[image]

Why it makes 1st latitude and last longitude 0.0 ?

Question related to this is : [Convert String of CLLocationCoordinate2D(s) into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163822/convert-string-of-cllocationcoordinate2ds-into-array)

**My requirement** 
And I want output in this way and store it in **let coordinates**.

```
let coordinates = [
(-122.63748, 45.52214),
(-122.64855, 45.52218),
(-122.6545, 45.52219),
(-122.65497, 45.52196),
(-122.65631, 45.52104),
(-122.6578, 45.51935),
(-122.65867, 45.51848),
(-122.65872, 45.51293) ]
```

**Encoding**
I'm encoding like this way, And encoding is 100% giving correct result.

```
 func encodeCoordinates(coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]) -> String {
//        let flattenedCoords: [String] = coords.map { coord -> String in "\(coord.latitude):\(coord.longitude)" }
        let flattenedCoords: [String] = coords.map { coord -> String in "\(coord.latitude):\(coord.longitude)"}
        let encodedString: String = flattenedCoords.joined(separator: ",")
        print("[\(encodedString)]")
        return encodedString
    }
```

It's Output is :
[image]

**Error in decoding**

I'm decoding in this way. I'm using this code, It's same like as  [Convert String of CLLocationCoordinate2D(s) into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44163822/convert-string-of-cllocationcoordinate2ds-into-array)  But not giving me correct result.

```
func decodeCoordinates(encodedString: String) -> [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
    let flattenedCoords: [String] = encodedString.components(separatedBy: ",")
    let coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = flattenedCoords.map { coord -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        let split = coord.components(separatedBy: ":")
        if split.count == 2 {
            let latitude: Double = Double(split[0]) ?? 0.0
            let longitude: Double = Double(split[1]) ?? 0.0
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        } else {
            return CLLocationCoordinate2D()
        }
    }
    return coords
}

func makingRouteOfFreeRide(){

print("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n oooooo \(ProfileRoutesVC.map)\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n",decodeCoordinates(encodedString: ProfileRoutesVC.map))
let a = decodeCoordinates(encodedString: ProfileRoutesVC.map)
```

[image]

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make it on-topic. Simply linking to another question won't make it on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your input string look like this:

```
let yourCoordinateString = "[32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229]"
```

```
func decodeCoordinates(encodedString: String) -> [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
    var tmpString = encodedString
    tmpString.removeFirst(1)
    tmpString.removeLast(1)

    let flattenedCoords: [String] = tmpString.components(separatedBy: ",")
    let coords: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] = flattenedCoords.map { coord -> CLLocationCoordinate2D in
        let split = coord.components(separatedBy: ":")
        if split.count == 2 {
            let latitude: Double = Double(split[0]) ?? 0.0
            let longitude: Double = Double(split[1]) ?? 0.0
                return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
            } else {
                return CLLocationCoordinate2D()
            }
        }

        return coords
}
```

Comment: Sir,  let coordinates = [
            (-122.63748, 45.52214),
            (-122.64855, 45.52218),
            (-122.6545, 45.52219),
            (-122.65497, 45.52196),
            (-122.65631, 45.52104),
            (-122.6578, 45.51935),
            (-122.65867, 45.51848),
            (-122.65872, 45.51293) ] this is the Output I want

Comment: **"32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229"**

Assuming u have this string of coordinate right?

Comment: Please try that input and just apply decode function

Comment: Input: [My Input Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tvs8pveGW2-UhMcDwZEU5kW75KzUJ14B/view?usp=sharing)

Output: [My Output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18vGc3jBDhtZWV7LLSISspcpSzEnLrqBW/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Actually this array is closed in Square Brackets.  [32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229], So how to handle this ?

Comment: Please see this.

Comment: Do you mean the inputString? Like this? **"[32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229]"***

Comment: Yes Bro.   [32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229,32.4945:74.5229]

Comment: If that's the string that you input into your method, it's 100% wrong.
Because of encodedString.components(separatedBy: ",") will split and the first element "[someCoorString" and when you put that into Double([someCoorString) it's gonna return nil. Same goes to the last element

Comment: I've updated your `decodeCoordinates` method. check my above code again. That method will work in your case "[your coordinate string, your coordinate string]"

Comment: I have a question, Is using encoder decoder is best or using this method ?

Comment: It doesn't matter. We're just adapting to the response from API. Choose what make your code work ;)